# Understanding new Object() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have the following code -

```
var a = new Object();
var b = {};
console.log(a == b || a === b);
```

and it prints `false`. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: `==` uses the [*The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), `===` uses the [*The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6). They're not hard to understand, where the Type of value being evaluated is the same (in this case Object) they do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare the equality of objects you compare whether the two objects have the same instance (meaning that the variables you compare do reference the same memory).

You have two different instances, so equality comparison yields false.

If you want to check if all properties of two objects have equal values it is a different thing and you really have to check equality for each object property.

Answer (score 6):

When you compare objects, you are testing to see if they are *the same object*.

You have two different (albeit effectively identical) objects.

Comment: Just adding to this, if you did want to compare its type you can use `instanceof`... `console.log(a instanceof Object);`

Comment: No, I wanted to compare the values of the objects.

Comment: Your answer is correct. But answer this for me: is the first one not an instance of an object and the second one just an empty object?

Comment: @Mikey — Both are instances of the object "class". Both are empty objects. You just used different syntax to create them.

Comment: a = new Object(); b = a; This will yield a "true" when compared

Comment: var a = {id:'1'};  var b = new Object(a);  will yield equivalence as well.

Comment: @SimonStaton— *instanceof* isn't intended to compare type, *typeof* is. The object returned by a constructor is usually not the same type (constructors are functions, the returned object is usually a plain object), so where *instanceof* returns true, *typeof* will almost always return false.

Comment: @Mikey—`{}` is defined as being identical to `new Object()`, see [*ECMA-262 §11.1.5 Object Initialiser*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5).